# SendMessageCallback не вызывает функцию callback

Tags: c++, api

Не могу понять в чём может быть ошибка. Код ниже никогда не вызывает функцию ResultCallBack. Смотрю через spy++ сообщения отсылаются и получается ответ, но функция колбэка при этом не вызывается, подскажите что я делаю не так?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>


bool test = false;

VOID CALLBACK ResultCallBack(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, ULONG_PTR dwData, LRESULT 
lResult) {
    test = true;  
}

int main() {

    HWND hwnd = (HWND)0x00120726;

    while (!test) {
        SendMessageCallback(hwnd, WM_NCHITTEST, NULL, MAKELPARAM(555, 333), ResultCallBack, NULL);
       //получается бесконечный цикл
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

spy++
[image: spy++]

Comment: Откуда вы взяли значение `0x00120726`?

Comment: spy++ навёл на окно и получил его, так же spy++ отобраджает send и resive WM_NCHITTEST. сообщения проходят но callback не выполняется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessagecallbacka) же ясно написано

> If the target window belongs to a different thread from the caller, then the callback function is called only when the thread that called **SendMessageCallback** also calls **GetMessage**, **PeekMessage**, or **WaitMessage**.

Ваша программа явно делает `SendMessageCallback` для "чужого" окна. Поэтому пока ваша программа не сделает `GetMessage`, `PeekMessage`, or `WaitMessage`, ваш callback вызван не будет.

Мгновенный (синхронный) вызов callback происходит только в том случае, если вы вызываете `SendMessageCallback` для "своего" окна, т.е. окна, принадлежащего вызывающему потоку.

Comment: спасибо всё заработало